# Ad Manager (DFP) popup banner

Tags: ads, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I want to create a pop-up banner that serves Google Ad Manager ads.

It needs to be floating and to have X (CLOSE) in the top right corner. Popup needs to show up only if there is an active ad in Google Ad Manager.

Here is code example that I use:

```
<script async src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
<script>
window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
googletag.defineSlot('/108655xxx/posao-desktop-popup', [[320, 480], [300, 300], [500, 500]], 'div-gpt-ad-1656934240929-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
googletag.enableServices();
 });
</script>

<div style="left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 0);text-align: center;position: fixed;z- 
index: 9999;bottom: 0px;">
<div id='div-gpt-ad-1656934240xxx-0'>
<span onclick="this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';" style="color: white; position: absolute; top:3px; cursor: pointer; right:3px; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); padding: 2px 5px;">✕</span>

 <script>
 googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1656934240xxx-0'); });
 </script>
</div>
```

At desktop version of our website, close (X) button don't show up: https://prnt.sc/eqA1NRPjDgrq
And at mobile version of website, X showing even if there is no ads: https://prnt.sc/joCddWsfKCvP

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Popup ads are handled slightly different than regular display ads.
According to the official documentation, the correct method is to :

1. define an out of page slot (details [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/6088046?hl=en))
2. handle the rendering style within a custom template (details [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/1138308?hl=en))

First, we declare the out of page ad unit :

```
<script async src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
<script>
window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
//out-of-page ads.
  googletag.defineOutOfPageSlot('/xxxxxx/abcd', 'out-of-page-ad').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();
 });
</script>

<div id='out-of-page-ad'>
 <script>
 googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('out-of-page-ad'); });
 </script>
</div>
```

Second, you need to create a custom template in the Google Ad Manager UI.
This way, you make sure the popup rendering style is managed in the adserver.
Two things to keep in mind :

- your creative will be served within an iframe. Then you will have to
  choose between styling the ad iframe or creating a new dom node for
  your popup ad.
- an out of page ad iframe has a 1x1 size by default

Here is a code sample you play work with :

```
<script>
var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = '%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%%%DEST_URL%%';
        link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        link.style = 'position:fixed;z-index:9999;bottom:0px;left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 0);';
    
var popup = document.createElement('img');
        popup.src='[%creativeFile%]';
        popup.width = '320';
        popup.height = '480';

var close = document.createElement('span');
        close.style = 'color: white; position: absolute; top:3px; cursor: pointer; right:3px; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); padding: 2px 5px;z-index:10000;';
        close.innerHTML = 'X';
        close.onclick = function() { 
            link.style.display = 'none';
        };

top.document.body.appendChild(link)
link.appendChild(popup);
link.appendChild(close);

</script>
<!-- to make sure you count an impression -->
<img src="%%VIEW_URL_ESC%%" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

Of course, there are other ways to handle that kind of rendering (you could prepare a dedicated DOM node and the templates only fills the variables (image src, a href, size...etc). The previous code is a sample so you can work with and find the best solution.

Note : depending on the user ad experience you want to achieve, you could be interested in looking at their "web interstitial ad" (beta) solution detailed [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/9840201?hl=en) and [here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/samples/display-web-interstitial-ad).

Comment: Thanks a lot @rabsom.

Do you know any good tutorial how we can create custom template in Ad Mnager?
I was try to find some video tutorials, but no luck.

Comment: @DragnetPro : custom templates are mainly done with html / css and javascript codes executed from an iframe... No specific tutorials sorry, you will have to test on your own. The above "code sample" should help you achieving creating your own custom template.